# Security Exception: Not allowed to start a service Intent

Tags: android

Ok i am new to android development so please bear with me here. I am following the learning android book and have this problem where the refresh service wont work as it doesnt have the necessary permission. Can anyone tell me what is causing the issue? The logcat throws up runtime error: ****java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.example.yamba/.RefreshService } without permission com.example.yamba.permission.REFRESH at com.example.yamba.TimelineActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(TimelineActivity.java:138)***
*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.yamba"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.yamba.permission.REFRESH" />

<application
    android:name=".YambaApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.yamba.StatusActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/status_Update" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TimelineActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".UpdaterService" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".RefreshService"
        android:permission="com.example.yamba.permission.REFRESH" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.yamba.RefreshService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".PrefsActivity"
        android:label="@string/Preferences" >
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="com.example.yamba.REFRESH_ALARM" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

```
package com.example.yamba;

import java.util.List;

import winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.Status;
import winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class RefreshService extends IntentService {
    static final String TAG = "RefreshService";

    public RefreshService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            ((YambaApp) getApplication()).pullAndInsert();
        Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "OnCreated");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        Log.d(TAG, "OnDestroy");
    }

}



    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent intentUpdater = new Intent(this, UpdaterService.class);
    Intent intentRefresh = new Intent(this, RefreshService.class);
    Intent intentPrefs = new Intent(this, PrefsActivity.class);
    Intent intentTimeline = new Intent(this, StatusActivity.class);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.item_start_service:
        startService(intentUpdater);
        return true;
    case R.id.item_stop_service:
        stopService(intentUpdater);
        return true;
    case R.id.item_refresh:
        startService(intentRefresh);
        return true;
    case R.id.item_prefs:
        startActivity(intentPrefs);
        return true;
    case R.id.item_status_update:
        startActivity(intentTimeline);
    default:
        return false;

    }
```

The onOptionsItemSelected is used to call the refresh service.

Really Appreciate the help. Thanks!!

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace, along with the code where you are trying to arrange to start this service.

Comment: CommonsWare i added the stack trace from the Logcat just now.

Comment: See @jvra's answer -- you have to have a `<permission>` element for any custom-defined permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare this REFRESH Permission in the manifest as well. 
here is an example code of how to declare a permission

```
<permission
    android:name="A_PERMISSION"
    android:description="@string/broadcast_permission_desc"
    android:label="@string/broadcast_permission_label"
    android:permissionGroup="@string/broadcast_permission_group"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

For Reference See this [Page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#declaring)

Comment: I already tried that before using the <uses-permission>. It still throws the same error when using <permission> on the manifest file.

Comment: dude you need to use both of them, user-permission as well as permission. Not just Any one !

Comment: I somehow always keep forgetting to declare both of them in the manifest. Thanks for the help Ishan Khanna!

Answer (score 2):

you need to declare `permission` in your manifest

```
    <permission 
        android:name="com.example.yamba.permission.REFRESH"        
        android:protectionLevel="signature"
    />
```

Comment: I already tried that before using the <uses-permission>. It still throws the same error when using <permission> on the manifest file.

Comment: Then you could check if you have a default constructor in your service class

Comment: jvra the issue has been resolved. I missed out using the <uses-permission> and the <permission> tag in the manifest, hence the error. But thanks for your help.!!